# How does one extend function objects using generics?

Tags: typescript

In the code below, how should one define these types, such that `Bar` extends `Foo` and `FooBar`'s return type is `'a'`

```js
interface Foo { 
    (...args: any):any
    b: string
}

interface Bar<T extends string> extends Foo {
     (a:T):T
     b: T 
}
// type of BarA below is {
//    (a:'a'):'a'
//    b: 'a' 
// } I assume?
type BarA = Bar<'a'> 

type FooBarWorks = BarA['b'] // 'a' as expected
type FooBar = ReturnType<BarA> // any - why not 'a'?
```

[code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN7IFDKHIAUAdOXFAOYDOAXMnCAJ4CUdTzBRARgzWCigqeAL548oSLEQoAQpQA8AFWQQAHpBAATGsgFCQVAHxrNEHXoxZs3IsTh1l7ZXcJ9kqsXgD0P5GDMAA4o6DDIClAAgsg8EAA26ADuyMB6tn5EJI4A5HA57Hk5vv68DEX4maLIAJKMNDQArgC2EAD8eIEhEZQxALw9UIpFphJdKNaRAOroUADWegORUQDaOTw5ALrImRVwehohCJDancETmJHIAwBKEGCNUCDK54rLppmcyAC0yEkAFsxkCB0GBkEU2kA)

Can someone also explain to me why this code doesn't work as I expected it to work?

Thanks.

EDIT:
this solution fixes the problem:

```js
type Bar<T extends string> = {
     (a:T):T
     b: T 
} extends infer O extends Foo ? O : never
```

but why doesn't my interface solution above work?

Comment: Your `BarA` type has *two* call signatures, one is `(...args: any)=>any` and the other is `(a: "a")=>"a"`.  If you had a value `f` of type `BarA`, then `f(100)` is of type `any`, not `"a"`. Why would you expect `ReturnType<BarA>` to be `"a"` as opposed to `any`?   I'm trying to understand whether this is a simple misconception on your part or whether you are aware of the two call signatures but have some reason for expecting `"a"` here.

Comment: @jcalz - thanks I do know about multiple call signatures.  But even [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nGA7KBeKAKAdDghgJwHMBnALilyRAEpUA+SkAKCYEslgJ8AzXAY2jw4UAN5QmUSVABG5YsHztCTAL4t2nHv2gAhAgB4AKlAgAPTkgAmxKPMVJCdE+YhWbQgDSwEyURKmYuKSG1MH+UrJQxqpMAPSxUKCQUHDcUHr4AIIyEAA2cADuUKw2InEJUhhBAOS41aG11eUBkY3i8VAqUACSFMTEAK4AthAA-ExJugTZ6Bn6jU4sk95wGQDqcPgA1jaz0wDa1dLVALpQHW24NmaQfJyWE+CCCBloUABKEMAD+EiGT-oMpknB1GFAALRQAoACxAUCQcGAUEaoyAA) it doesn't work - why?

Comment: @jcalz - I think I've snapped it now - what you are saying is `(a: "a")=>"a"` when it extends `(...args: any)=>any` doesn't replace it, but rather is in addition to it, which is why it's returning `any` - which is the broadest type?

Comment: Yes, there are two call signatures, not one.  When you `infer` from multiple call signatures, the compiler picks the last one (lowest precedence).  Your `BarA` type is equivalent to `{(a: "a"):"a"; (...args: any):any}` because the inherited signature takes lower precedence.  Does this fully explain it now?  If so I'll write up an answer.  If not, what remains to be explained?

Comment: @jcalz - yes thanks that does fully explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your types, `BarA` is equivalent to

```
type BarA = {
    (a: "a"): "a";
    (...args: any): any;
    b: "a"
}
```

Extending an interface with a call signature and providing another call signature results in a type with *two* call signatures.  The new call signature does not replace the old one, it is added as the first call signature in an [overloaded](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) function type.

You can verify this yourself:

```
declare const barA: BarA;
const aRes = barA("a"); // (a: "a") => "a" (+1 overload)
// const aRes: "a"
const bRes = barA("b"); // (...args: any) => any (+1 overload)
// const bRes: any
```

Therefore [`ReturnType<BarA>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) is going to give you the return type of one of those two call signatures.  `ReturnType` is [implemented](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/8af8f3c4d1e5cc6654916de9f42e9ba370513157/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L1624) via [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) as introduced by [microsoft/TypeScript#21496](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21496), and:

> When inferring from a type with multiple call signatures (such as the type of an overloaded function), inferences are made from the *last* signature

So you get the last call signature, which is `(...args: any) => any`.  And its return type is `any`:

```
type FooBar = ReturnType<BarA> 
// type FooBar = any
```

---

Presumably you were trying to *override* the call signature instead of *overloading* it.  But TypeScript doesn't seem to support that directly.  Probably the most expedient approach is not to extend `Foo` directly, but `Foo` without the call signature:

```
interface Bar<T extends string> extends Pick<Foo, keyof Foo> {
    (a: T): T
    b: T
}
```

Then you get a `Bar` with a single call signature of the expected shape:

```
type BarA = Bar<'a'>
/* type BarA = {
    (a: "a"): "a";
    b: "a"
}*/
```

And `ReturnType` behaves as desired:

```
type FooBar = ReturnType<BarA>
// type FooBar = "a"
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHIAUAdGXFAOYDOAXMnCAJ4CU9jT+hARvdWFFCVcAX1y5QkWIhQAhCgB4AKsggAPSCAAm1ZP0EhKAPlUaI23Rix5CxOPSVtkSrgV7PR4sEwAOcigCCyAC8yPJQCgDkcJFGuAD0AFTI3n5hgSE4rnb0AERwuU75uQDc2aTkVHQMzE4cZbbuxaKJ8eJaEAgANhQoCOgg-MjcgfThAWX9g2AMAEoQuqEjUAFExSwlyPHxOcjrISbFxADUAIzI6ABu0F3ocFosCTtTQ3Dz1c0vM9zvmcuruW4hU222IZBIFBo7FqBxqTBO5yuNzuDyeyC+w3e0M4Xl8KCs4Uy8zAAFcoCAlHiFOM4qDUvjMITQhxxCA4ABbBY+GRoYBqLLZSTQeBIdIRFTqTQ6PQCIQmSXmaUABWACAA1gorAAaZBqiBMdAwNCYEw2WyEIj2ZxOFzmngObJibL0sVBULhKIxOK2JIpPGuzJmu2WvIFIoFBp24ah3KO1riWwugkUIkQUnkyl+amBb2EOn+5NQTLNURAA)

Comment: Thank you for your time in providing this answer.  Your solutions are always amazing.